# Find Excel three-columns match in two different sheets

Tags: excel, match, vlookup, worksheet-function, accounting

I've three  sheets from differents periods of several companies

It happens that not same accounts were used on all periods. I need to compare two or three companies from two different periods. I've managed to pull out the data from any company on another sheet using HLOOKUP and works like a charm, **what I need is to populate also the account name field.**

I was thinking that probably and IF formula could work, something like if that cell = 0 then populate nothing but if ≠ 0 then populate the account field name

But on sheets not all account are on same column. its like

```
    - 5701 · Construction Supplies            
       - 57011 · Construction Supplies - Other    
  - Total 5701 · Construction    Supplies
```

Please note that for comparison purpose I need same accounts on same rows so if second company didnt used - 57011 · Construction Supplies - Other
then when populate should be like

5701 · Construction Supplies

(Blank row)

Total 5701 · Construction    Supplies

So,  how could i do this?

thanks in advance

Comment: Question is overly broad. Please narrow it down, include your VBA code snippet and highlight the problematic part (you can use a use Macro Recorder as a helper). Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

The question is overly broad, so I am giving you a generic answer.

First, find out how many different accounts (totally) do you have. It might be 200 (as per 3rd sheet), or more. In a second scenario, copy all accounts Ids from 3 Worksheets into the column in 4th one and remove duplicates: you will get the total number (for example 250 accounts). Next, clear that range and paste entire range data from aforementioned 3 Worksheets into the 4th one starting with 1st, 251st and 501st rows, correspondingly.

Hope this may help.